# Should I look for job change or continue?

Tags: software-industry, job-change, work-life-balance, job-satisfaction

It's been about 16 months in to the job but for 14 months I was working in Customer Success team, about two months ago I was moved into Delivery team.

I have a feeling that I am not able to meet the expectation of my colleagues and I don't have the confidence to own the work which is assigned to me, because I work as an associate business analyst in IT, so most of my work is related to documenting business requirements of clients and then explain everything about it to dev and qa leads.

What happens is that after reading the initial feature or request submission by the client I have the general idea of the requirement and I write it down in the user stories but even the simplest of request requires me to dig deeper and this takes time resulting in delay in handing it off to devs and qa. Then after some time client would come back and ask whether we have taken x thing into consideration then this back and forth continues. This is affecting work-life balance if that's even a thing post pandemic.

I am considering job change but I am not sure whether it is too early to think about that or should I wait for the offices to open and maybe things would be different working from the office.

Another issue with considering job change is that I have 3 months notice period and also my financial condition is not that good to leave without offer in hand.

To put things into perspective I find myself sitting in front of the laptop more than 12 hours a day, 5 days a week. But I can only log 8 hours a day. Since if I log more than that management may question on what I am doing overtime.

Saturdays and Sundays are mostly free but still the fact that there is some work pending bothers me over the weekend.

Comment: Were you ready for the new role? The way you represent it, it sounds like that came as a surprise to you.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't have the choice it is decided by the management.

Comment: So, if you're given a role for which you're neither ready nor willing to pursue as a future career path, and you can't change that arrangement, the only way left is to find another employer where you can get the role you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got to the point that a you want to leave your job you should consider that you have nothing to lose. You should begin to log some of the overtime hours and when managers ask why you are logging them just explain that you are under pressure and you need time to learn how to work properly in this role. If managers make some nice speeches, but then they tell you to stop logging the overtime hours it means that they already knew it and they pushed on purpose more than you can handle in order to get some free work.

If you have a  three months notice period I assume they have the same notice period to fire you. It means that before actually firing you they will think trice and they will be very keen to solve the situation before they have to get to that point. If on the other hand they have a much shorter notice period than yours it means that you are in a contract that is a sort of trap, you better get out of it asap.