# How to tackle uncertainty about job requirements?

Tags: software-industry, job-change, work-life-balance, stress

I am working as an Associate Business Analyst at a fintech firm and I am facing following issues:

1. Since this is a BA role it requires me to frequently check the product functionality through manual testing which I do not like.
2. The scenarios for testing and expected output are not very clear in some cases because my team lead is new to the firm and he is also not very clear about the scenarios.
3. The testing is done on client environment which is accessed through VDI which is slow to perform.
4. There are some client meetings which are scheduled late at night 8 - 9 pm which kills work life balance

These reasons are adding stress to my life and I am not sure if I would be able to continue with this. What should I do? Should I look for another job?

I find myself starting to work at 10 am and wrap it up around 8 to 9 pm which is about 11 hours daily. Is this normal? When I joined I had the expectation of doing the job 9 to 5 so that I can do other things other than work in life.

But now I barely get any time. Plus this WFH is killing work life balance and company has extended it till further notice. Because if it was an office job most probably I would not take any work home but now there is no distinction between work and home. Home is work and work is home I feel so bad about myself and feel like crying everyday.

Comment: Same job as you are talking about in your question here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/173413/should-i-look-for-job-change-or-continue ?

Comment: @iLuvLogix Yes.

Comment: Why wouldn't you look? The subtext of this question is that you know you want to leave and are looking for a confidence boost. Look for a new job. Meanwhile, quit working at 6 pm then join the call at 8. Or so.

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is the standard life of a BA, so maybe you have selected the wrong line of business if you dislike it that much. Sure, in your case there are more issues due to unclear business requirements, but that is to be addressed by the PO (Product Owner) that is not doing their job as expected. One more thing: the BA is not a QA Engineer, so your testing is functional, to ensure that your requirements are met by the developers from a business perspective. This is what you are supposed to do as a BA.

About WFH bleeding into your personal life, that is all you, not WFH. While you WFH you have more time to yourself and yours because you don't have to commute, but is up to you to turn off the work when the business hours are ended. Sure, sometimes there are time-zone driven calls, but that happens in the office as well, which is even more disruptive because you won't be able to leave until the call ends. You have to be flexible, so if this evening you have a 1-hour late call you start 1 hour later tomorrow: that's how it works.